# Template Access Restriction Redirection is not working

Tags: templates, redirects

I have a template where I only want "Members" to be able to access. If a user that is not part of the "Members" group tries to access that page, I want it to redirect to a `sign-up/index`

Here is what I did in the templates

[image]

However, my problem is that when I tried accessing this certain template as "Guest", I only see a blank page. I am not redirected to `sign-in/index`.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use template access restrictions, EE doesn't do a browser redirect to your no-access template (`sign-in/index`)--it just displays that template in-place.

For example, if you browse to `/members-only` in your browser and that's a template with the access restriction, EE will display the `sign-in/index` template at the `/members-only` URL.

So, first of all, make sure that you see what you want when you browse to `/sign-in` in your browser -- make sure that's not blank. Also be sure that you don't have any conflicting template access restrictions on `sign-in/index`!

Then, if that's OK, check that your code in `sign-in/index` can adapt to the different URLs where it will be displayed.

Does any of that help?

Comment: I see. So it just replaces what it shows, not redirect. In other to redirect, I have to use conditionals in the template and use {redirect}, right?

Comment: You can do access restrictions totally with conditions--I like to do this with the IfElse and HTTP Header add-ons: `{exp:ifelse parse="inward"}
{if logged_out}{exp:http_header status="301" location="/register/login" terminate="yes"}{if:else}`... Or, you can use the EE Template Access Restrictions, and then have EE point to an "unauthorized" page that's just a redirect to your sign-in page, e.g., `{redirect="sign-in/index"}`.